# Match link tag with any attribute

Tags: regex, grep

I have the following regex that I use in InDesign (uses GREP):

```
(?<=<link>)[^<link>]+(?=</link>)
```

How do I match links with the href attribute also?

Comment: Note that `[^<link>]` will match only characters that aren't a `<`, an `l`, an `i`, an `n`, a `k` or a `>`, not the entire string `<link>`. `.+?` might be a better idea.

Comment: You want the full element like `<link href="asdsada">adsasd</link>` and can there be elements in side the link like `<link href="x"><div>asd</div></link>, and if so, will there be a link element within a link?

Comment: I want the full element [code]<link href="asdsada">adsasd</link>[/code]....there won't be any elements inside the link and there won't be nested links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the regex.  It matches everything from <link to </link>

```
<link[^>]*href[^>]*>.*?</link>
```

Here are the results showing what will and will not work with this regex.

```
<link href="asdsada" />  EMPTY FAILS  
<link href="asdsada">adsasd</link>  NORMAL OK 
<link href="asdsada"><div>asdasdsa</div></link>  NESTED ELEMENTS OK
<link href="asdasda"><link>asdasd</link></link>  NESTED Link FAILS
```

You can also use groups to capture the href attribute and inner content.  Though if you want the href attribute you have to count on the quotes being in there.

```
<link[^>]*href="([^"]*)"[^>]*>(.*?)</link>
```

Comment: You're forcing `href` to appear - I'm not sure this is desired (I think OP want to match `<link>` and `<link href=...>`). I'd probably just have removed `href[^>]*`.

Comment: @Dukeling, that's how I interepreted the statement: "How do I match links with the href attribute also?"  But you're right I am requiring `href` and it can be removed the way you suggest.